# Unexpected multiple spaces instead of one in figure caption

Tags: spacing, floats, captions, urls

I am facing an issue with image caption when I tried to add a source to it. I don't want the source to show in \listoffigures. The way I found to achieve it, is by adding command

```
\newcommand*{\captionsource}[2]{%
  \caption[{#1}]{%
    #1%
    \\\hspace{\linewidth}%
    {Źródło:} #2%
  }%
}
```

and then in my file, I use it as follow

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{arduino}
\captionsource{Opis wejść oraz wyjść Arduino Nano 33 BLE}{\url{https://content.arduino.cc/assets/Pinout-NANOble_latest.pdf}}
\label{fig:arduino}
\end{figure}
```

But instead of expected

```
Figure 1: Caption (This works as it should)
Source: My_Url (Here I Want one space between the colon and my URL, which doesn't work)
```

I either get no spaces in source if I'll remove the single space from the command \captionsource in line `{Źródło:} #2%`, and the link is glued to the colon (Source:My_Url) or single space results in this:

[image]

It's my first paper in Latex, I hope you can help me since I can't find the solution by myself.

Comment: your url has not enough breakpoints. You can try the xurl package which allow it to break in more places, or set the caption in ragged right (how depends on your class and your packages).

Comment: Changing the package "url" to "xurl" did the trick! If you'll post it as answer I'll gladly accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your url has not enough breakpoints. You can try the `xurl` package which allows it to break in more places, or set the caption in ragged right (how depends on your class and your packages).

Comment: Thank you for your help, xurl solved the issue.